# Grep Syntax Dilemna

Tags: regex, linux, unix, sed, grep

I'm trying to use `grep` to copy out lines in a text file that match a certain pattern but, I'm running into some issues... I would like to grab the values in the "title=" container.

**Code:**

```
get_tmax=`grep '[0-9][0-9]&deg;C' K0G7_ec_tmp`
echo "${get_tmax}" > K0G7_ec_tmp2
```

**Text File Contents:**

```
<p class="one" title="19&deg;C">19</p>
<p class="two" title="26&deg;C">26</p>
```

Comment: it is not very clear what you are doing here. Are you storing the command in a variable and then running it? It is normally and not very good idea. Also, what is the expected output?

Comment: Use an XML parser (xmllint, xmlstarlet ... ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `grep -P` with match reset `\K`:

```
grep -ioP 'title="\K[^"]+' K0G7_ec_tmp
19&deg;C
26&deg;C
```

However take caution while parsing HTML file using shell utilities grep/awk/sed etc. Better to use dedicated HTML parser for this job.

Answer (score 0):

`grep` is shorthand for `g/re/p` which is not exactly what you're trying to do so I'd look at `sed` for this:

```
$ sed 's/.*title="\([^"]*\).*/\1/' file
19&deg;C
26&deg;C
```

That will work with any sed version on any OS.